# In a set of HTML radio buttons, how to highlight the correct/wrong choice

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are three HTML radio buttons with ids `1`, `2`, `3` and some text next to them. The "correct" answer is `2`. When the user selects `2`, the radio button and it's text should be highlighted with a green color. Otherwise, (choices `1` and `3`) they should be highlighted with red. How can this behavior be achieved with HTML,CSS and/or JavaScript?

This is what I've tried so far (Instead of radio button I am highlighting the border of an image)

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="1" class="input-hidden"/>
<label for="1">
  <img src="1.jpg"/>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="2" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="2">
  <img src="2.jpg"/>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label>img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's always a good practice to post the code regarding what have you tried so that others can guide you rather than straight up asking for a solution.

Comment: `input[type=radio]:checked + label>img` which sets the current selected radio button to the desired color, but I can't have two colors like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add class to the img to separate the wrong and correct answers.

```css
input[type=radio]:checked+label>.wrongAnswer {
  border: 1px solid #990000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #990000;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label>.correctAnswer {
  border: 1px solid #090;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="1" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="1">
  <img class="wrongAnswer" src="1.jpg"/>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="2" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="2">
  <img class="correctAnswer" src="2.jpg"/>
</label>
<input type="radio" name="group1" id="3" class="input-hidden" />
<label for="3">
  <img class="wrongAnswer" src="3.jpg"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nth-of-type` selector to identify the nth element. Note for this selector to work properly you have to group your inputs because it's the nth-of-type within the same parent read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssreF/sel_nth-of-type.asp).

```
input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(2):checked + label > img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}
```

### Update

A comment said that this only works if all the answers are 2. That is correct. You need to target the answer for each question separately.

```
<div id="q1">
  <!-- inputs -->
</div>

<div id="q2">
  <!-- inputs -->
</div>

<div id="q3">
  <!-- inputs -->
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
/* First answer for Q1 */
#q1 input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(1):checked + label > img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}

/* Fourth answer for Q2 */
#q2 input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(4):checked + label > img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}

/* Third answer for Q3 */
#q3 input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(3):checked + label > img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}
```

Easily combined as:

```
#q1 input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(1):checked + label > img,
#q2 input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(4):checked + label > img,
#q3 input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(3):checked + label > img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}
```

```css
input[type=radio]:checked + label > img {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px red;
}

#q1 input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(1):checked + label > img,
#q2 input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(2):checked + label > img,
#q3 input[type=radio]:nth-of-type(3):checked + label > img{
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #090;
}
```

```html
<div id="q1">
  First one is correct:
  
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="q1-1" class="input-hidden"/>
  <label for="q1-1">
    <img src="1.jpg"/>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="q1-2" class="input-hidden" />
  <label for="q1-2">
    <img src="2.jpg"/>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group1" id="q1-3" class="input-hidden" />
  <label for="q1-3">
    <img src="3.jpg"/>
  </label>
 </div>
 
 <div id="q2">
  Second one is correct:
  
  <input type="radio" name="group2" id="q2-1" class="input-hidden"/>
  <label for="q2-1">
    <img src="1.jpg"/>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" id="q2-2" class="input-hidden" />
  <label for="q2-2">
    <img src="2.jpg"/>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group2" id="q2-3" class="input-hidden" />
  <label for="q2-3">
    <img src="3.jpg"/>
  </label>
 </div>
 
  <div id="q3">
  Last one is correct:
  
  <input type="radio" name="group3" id="q3-1" class="input-hidden"/>
  <label for="q3-1">
    <img src="1.jpg"/>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group3" id="q3-2" class="input-hidden" />
  <label for="q3-2">
    <img src="2.jpg"/>
  </label>
  <input type="radio" name="group3" id="q3-3" class="input-hidden" />
  <label for="q3-3">
    <img src="3.jpg"/>
  </label>
 </div>
```

Comment: Correct, that's the case the OP has. He/she would have to create all the use cases. I'll update the answer.

Comment: This looks overcomplicated. This is a way to go tho.